# Why NetBeans 11 shows parameter name beside value while calling a method?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-11

[image: Here is a picture]

On line 11 the foo() method is called and beside the parameter value it shows the parameter name which i don't want and also there is a weird pink box along with the parameter name. How do i get rid of this. Tried many things on settings and found no solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's trying to help you. Be happy. It doesn't affect the execution of your program.

Comment: Search the settings of NetBeans, there's likely to be a "turn of parameter hints" or something like that.

Comment: You probably have Kotlin activated somewhere. .

Comment: @Slaw I've searched everything on the settings, found nothing like that and then came here asking for help.

Comment: @Sedrick that somewhere is where?

Comment: @user207421 Nothing to be happy. It does affect my code readability.

Comment: I was just guessing. There doesn't seem to be a Kotlin plugin for 11+.  I would upgrade to Netbeans 12.3  and not bring any old settings. Did you install any plugins lately? If you did, try uninstalling them one by one until you see the change you are looking for.

Comment: These are 2 separate things: (1) In NetBeans 12.2 (and I am I assuming it's the same for your version) there is an option from the main menu: View > Show Inline Hints. This causes those items in a smaller font to be displayed/hidden, such as your `data:` hint. (2) The red/pink borders are related to text which has been auto-completed for you by NetBeans. I believe if you just type somewhere else then that border disappears (because you have implicitly "accepted" the autocomplete suggestion).

Comment: @andrewjames: Though i had uninstalled Netbeans 11 then installed Netbeans 12 and that solved the problem but you gave the actual solution to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

In menu:

View | Show Inline Hints

Answer (score 7):

These are 2 separate things:

---

**(1) Inline Hints**

In NetBeans 12.2 (and I am I assuming it's the same for your version) there is an option from the main menu:

View > Show Inline Hints

[image]

This causes those items in a smaller font to be displayed/hidden, such as your data: hint.

---

**(2) Autocompletion Hints**

The red/pink borders are related to text which has been auto-completed for you by NetBeans. I believe if you just type somewhere else then that border disappears (because you have implicitly "accepted" the autocomplete suggestion).