# NetBeans feature how to turn off

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, netbeans-15

I have installed NetBeans 15. There is a feature that they have turned on by default that I find very distracting. How do I turn it off? It is the highlighted code in the image below:

[image]

This is a non editable extra text and for me just gets in the way.

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why NetBeans 11 shows parameter name beside value while calling a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896195/why-netbeans-11-shows-parameter-name-beside-value-while-calling-a-method)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to a work colleague found the answer. Turn off "Show Inline Hints" below :

[image]